# closest thing to arrays in Elixir

Tags: arrays, tuples, elixir

what is the closest thing to Arrays in Elixir. By arrays I mean, a container for values which I can access in constant time.

I've looked at tuple, but according to the [documentation](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Tuple.html):

> Tuples are not meant to be used as a “collection” type (which is also suggested by the absence of an implementation of the Enumerable protocol for tuples): they’re mostly meant to be used as a fixed-size container for multiple elements.

What I actually want to do:
I want to store *n* processes in an *array* and periodically pick a random process and send it a message.
I'm open to other suggestions too.

Comment: Do you want to be able to remove and insert processes as well?

Comment: @Dogbert: I'll add processes once but I need to remove process (less frequent operation) to simulate node going down.

Comment: Tuples have `O(n)` deletion. I'd go with storing this in a Map which takes `O(log n)` time for access/insert/delete. There's no data structure in Erlang/Elixir with `O(1)` access and faster than `O(n)` deletion.

Comment: @Dogbert: yes, `Map` is my last resort, I just want to make sure I'm not missing any data structure.

Comment: @Dogbert: BTW what would you suggest if I don't want to be able to insert and remove processes.

Comment: For the fastest possible access time, tuples. It's stored in memory like an Array is stored in imperative languages. You can construct it initially from a list using `List.to_tuple/1` in `O(n)` time.

Comment: relevant https://stackoverflow.com/a/35685220/2066155

Comment: Why not using Lists ?

Comment: Oh got it, because of the access time... what about ets?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I ended up using a combination of `list` and [`registry`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Registry.html) since I was working with processes. I got many responses on [Elixir forum](https://elixirforum.com/t/arrays/8850/6) which I'm listing below for future reference:

1. [`Tuple`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Tuple.html): stored continuous in memory, constant access time, editing results in copying whole structure. Does **not** implement Enumerable protocol.
2. linked-[`List`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/List.html): O(n) access time, prefixing is cheaper than suffixing. Implements Enumerable protocol.
3. [`Map`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Map.html): O(log n) read, write, delete time. Also implements Enumerable protocol.
4. [`:array`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/array.html): `array` module from Erlang.
5. [`registry`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Registry.html): (applicable only if storing processes) A local, decentralized and scalable key-value process storage.

Also, note 2 and 3 (List and Map) [are persistent data structures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30203227/does-elixir-have-persistent-data-structures-similar-to-clojure).

Comment: Tuples are stored "contiguously"

Answer (score 3):

There are also two Elixir packages [Arrays](https://github.com/Qqwy/elixir-arrays)
 and [Tensor](https://github.com/qqwy/tensor) that provide similar functionalities.

Answer (score 1):

Elixir has an array module via erlang: http://erlang.org/doc/man/array.html

Comment: The performance characteristics of this are completely different from arrays in imperative languages though, only the name is the same.

Comment: and @Dogbert could you expand on what those performance characteristics are?

Answer (score -3):

Like with `mapping` in the Solidity language, Elixir has `map()`.